# Okta angular sign in widget is not redirecting me

Tags: angular, typescript, okta

I just implemented Okta angular sign-in widget but I'm facing a problem,

I have multi modules where I have a authentication modules that handles sign-in, sign-out, sign-up...

this is the route that I want to reach at the end `localhost:4200/api/upload` but for a small convenience to keep all main routes together on my authentication module I just added a redirection between `localhost:4200/api/upload` and the `localhost:4200/sign-in` which is `{path: 'signed-in-redirect', pathMatch : 'full', redirectTo: 'api/upload'}`

So my `sign-in` page is on `localhost:4200/sign-in`, normally when I log-in with okta it should redirect me to `localhost:4200/signed-in-redirect` and this will redirect me to my desired path which is `localhost:4200/api/upload`, but it stick at the sign-in page it doesn't redirect this is my url after passing the sign-in `http://localhost:4200/sign-in?redirectURL=%2Fapi%2Fupload%3Fcode%3DkDPYjQPbut93pUXc3BR_04w4Xf8rn3c3y2eQXGNyOSc%26state%3DqEpxhsyhv13ZqZo0YteWJkWTBdNKX29bqaYrjTZEjhZVI0rAhRDtxYh1ykOJG16o`

sign-in.ts:

```
oktaSignin: any;

constructor(
    private oktaAuthService: OktaAuthService
) {

    this.oktaSignin = new OktaSignIn({
        baseUrl: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
        clientId: myAppConfig.oidc.clientId,
        redirectUri: myAppConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
        authParams: {
            pkce: true,
            issuer: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer,
            scopes: myAppConfig.oidc.scopes
        }
    });

}
ngOnInit(): void {

        this.oktaSignin.remove();

        this.oktaSignin.renderEl({
                el: '#okta-sign-in-widget'
            },
            (response) => {
                if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    this.oktaAuthService.signInWithRedirect();
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                throw error;
            }
        );
}
```

sign-in.html:

```
<div class="w-full max-w-80 sm:w-80 mx-auto sm:mx-0" id="okta-sign-in-widget"></div>
```

sign-in.routing.ts:

```
export const authSignInRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path     : '',
        component: AuthSignInComponent
    },
];
```

appConfig.ts:

```
export default {
    oidc: {
        clientId: 'clienId',
        issuer: 'https://mydomain/oauth2/default',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/signed-in-redirect',
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
    }
};
```

app.routing.ts:

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
    {path: '', pathMatch : 'full', redirectTo: 'api/upload'},
    {path: 'signed-in-redirect', pathMatch : 'full', redirectTo: 'api/upload'},

{
        path: '',
        canActivate: [NoAuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [NoAuthGuard],
        component: LayoutComponent,
        data: {
            layout: 'empty'
        },
        children: [
            {path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInModule)},
            {path: 'signed-in-redirect', component: OktaCallbackComponent},
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can tot get element with id '#okta-sign-in-widget' in NgOnInit. Try to render widget in ngAfterViewInit.